# passing an empty object as a reference in function

Tags: javascript

Why do we get difference in output in the below question?

Q1

```
function foo(x){
    x.x=20;
}

var abc= {};

foo(abc);

console.log(abc);// prints an object with x=20
```

Q2

```
function foo(x){
    x={
        y:10
        };

}


var abc= {};

foo(abc);

console.log(abc);// prints an empty object
```

What's the difference between the two, why does it print an empty object in second case.

Comment: in second case `x` and `abc` are different.`abc` is not referencing `x`.

Comment: Overwriting a function parameter (`x`) with a new value has no effect on the world outside the function. You should generally make a point to avoid doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Q1`, `foo` is holding the reference that's why changes reflect on everywhere.

But in `Q2`, you have re-initialised the passed variable which remove the previous reference and assigned a new one.

That's why `Q2` prints empty and before passing `abc` was an empty object, after passing to a method didn't change it.

Comment: Thanks anik I got my answer

Answer (score 1):

Read the commeted lines to understand

Q1

```
function foo(x){
    x.x=20;
}

var abc= {};

foo(abc); //foo set abc.x=20

console.log(abc);
```

Q2

```
function foo(x){
    x={
        y:10
        };

}


var abc= {};

foo(abc); //foo create a new object and assign it in x. So abc hold by x is overriden

console.log(abc);
```